# Android Compatibility package issues

Tags: android, location, package, compatibility

Hi My app is an Google api map. I would like it to be compatible with old android version sso I have included the android compatibility package jar v4 in the libs folder. In my manifest I have:

I have this service which starts when my app starts and I want it to update the location and then when the map will be loaded it will be faster. So I have this code in the onCreate method of my service:

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (isEmulator() || !isOnline())
        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    else
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    try {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location==null || location.getTime()>(new Date().getTime()-Constants.TIEMPO_ENTRE_LOC_UPDATE))

        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(provider, null);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the thing is when I launch the app on emulator **(google apis level 7)** I get this error:

01-02 12:21:30.971: E/AndroidRuntime(523): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.location.LocationManager.**requestSingleUpdate**
01-02 12:21:30.971: E/AndroidRuntime(523):  at com.tresipunt.scm.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:78)

Well of course I know requestsingleupdate is not available in earlier apis but isn't the compatibility package supposed to fix it? How could I solve the problem? thks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatbility package does not include the LocationManager. You can see available packages here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Using

Comment: you're right I din't understoood that compatibility thing I thought all the classes worked. thks